# How could Stutthof's inmates reach Palmnicken?

Tags: world-war-two, poland, nazism, death, concentration-camps

There's a [*Palmnicken Massacre* section](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stutthof_(KL)#Masakra_w_Palmnicken) in [Polish article](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stutthof_(KL)) about Stutthof concentration camp (not available in [English version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stutthof_concentration_camp)). It says (translation mine):

> The female prisoners of the sub-camps were directed to the north. In Palmnicken (today Yantarnyj), the Germans murdered about 3,000 women on the beach.

Given the location of Yantarnyj ([54°52′N 19°56′E](https://goo.gl/maps/uaaxY7tLWJxmzvJW7)) and Stutthof concentration camp ([54°19′N 19°09′E](https://goo.gl/maps/yyn5AhLnZT2ErMSs8)), not mentioning subcamps (that were far to the west than Stutthof itself) **it is impossible** to reach the destination on food, because one would have to cross the 130 m wide water strait next to [Festung Pillau](https://goo.gl/maps/QMJfL5wgpLGtMDNj8) (an entry to Vistula Lagoon):

[image]

How could women Stutthof's inmates reach the Palmnicken's Massacre site?

Is it possible that there were [lead by land](https://goo.gl/maps/QMJfL5wgpLGtMDNj8) (through Elbląg and Kaliningrad) in a 36 hr (180 km long) death march?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your error is to assume the [sub camps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stutthof_concentration_camp#Stutthof_sub_camps) were only to the west of Stuthoff. Numerous camps were in areas that are now in the Kaliningrad oblast (Gerdauen/Zheleznodorozhny, Heiligenbeil/Mamonowo, Jesau/Juschny and Seerappen/Lyublino), one of them even in Königsberg itself.

While besides Serappen all of these sites were some distance from Königsberg, the marches took several days to reach Palmnicken (from [memorialmuseums.org](https://www.memorialmuseums.org/eng/denkmaeler/view/774/Holocaustdenkmal-Palmnicken):

> As the Red Army was approaching, the SS dissolved the East Prussian sub-camps of Stutthof concentration camp in January 1945 and gathered the approximately 13,000 prisoners in Königsberg. On January 26, the SS...and their foreign helpers herded at least 5,000 Jewish women from Poland and Hungary onto a death march in the biting cold to Sambia peninsula on Baltic coast. Only 3,000 arrived in Palmnicken, the rest were murdered by the accompanying commando on the way there. On the evening of January 31, 1945, members of the local German Volkssturm...took the Jews to the beach. There the SS guards shot the Jewish women or drove them into the icy Baltic Sea in which they froze to death.